# Как в conemu сделать открытие 2 вкладок по умолчанию?

Tags: conemu

Как в conemu сделать открытие 2 вкладок по умолчанию? В 1-вой git bash, а вторая cmd

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Создайте где-нибудь файл с расширением txt и следующим содержимым:

```
{Bash::Git bash}
{Shells::cmd}
```

В настройках conemu перейдите на вкладку **Startup**, в группе **Startup options** выберите пункт **Tasks file** и укажите путь к созданному выше файлу.